# Python haversine formula in degrees is way off

Tags: python

This is all of my python code and it is very far off from returning the correct distance.  I broke apart the haversine formula and know that it is going wrong somewhere at `C`. `C` is way too large of a number to allow for `D` to return the correct distance.

```
from math import sin, cos, atan2, sqrt, pi

First are my functions then my main part of the code
#-----FUNCTIONS------

#Header function
def Header():
    print("This program will calculate the distance between two geographic points!")

#get_location function
def Get_location():
    userLat = input("\n\n Please enter the latitude of your location in decimal degrees: ")
    userLon = input("Enter the longitude of the location in decimal degrees: ")
    return (userLat, userLon)


#Calculate distance function
#def Distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
def Distance(location1, location2):
    radEarth = 6371 #km
    #location1 = Get_location()
    #location2 = Get_location()

    lat1 = location1[0]
    lon1 = location1[1]
    lat2 = location2[0]
    lon2 = location2[1]

    B = sin((lat1-lat2)/2)**2
    S = sin((lon1-lon2)/2)**2
    F = (cos(lat1))

    A = B + (F * (cos(lat2)) * S)


    C = 2 * (atan2(sqrt(A),sqrt(1-A)) * (180/pi))
    print(C)

    D = radEarth * C

    return D                                                       

This is the main part of my program

#-------MAIN---------

#Call header function
Header()
```

Begin do another loop while user continues:

```
doAnother = 'y'
while doAnother == 'y':

    #Collect location points from user
    location1 = Get_location()
    location2 = Get_location()
    print(location1)
    print(location2)
    #Calculate distance between locations
    distance = Distance(location1, location2)

    print('The distance between your two locations is: ' + str(distance))


    doAnother = raw_input('Do another (y/n)?'.lower())

#Display goodbye
print('Goodbye!')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're implementing the Haversine formula as described [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). (I've had to do the exact thing BTW.) You're correct there is a problem in `C`.

Your code (Python):

```
C = 2 * (atan2(sqrt(A),sqrt(1-A)) * (180/pi))
```

Code from the URL above (Javascript):

```
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
```

Problem is that you are converting `C` to degrees (with that `(180/pi)`), but the next calculation `D = radEarth * C` only makes mathematical sense if `C` is in radians.